# "Guaranteed Delivery" Messaging - should I use MQTT or ZeroMQ?

Tags: c++, rabbitmq, mqtt, zeromq, distributed-system

We need a lightweight client based messaging solution. We used AMQP, RabbitMQ before, but in C++ we have problems.

We would like to choose ZeroMQ with malamuteserver or MQTT ? Our IoT will publish data (45 kb) almost every 5 min.

We need to deliver this message 100% and do not want to lose any message.

We tried MQTT QoS level 2, but when server disconnected or main server client has a problem we are losing published messages.

We need exactly RabbitMQ task / worker model. Messages should queued in the server until consumers connected if anything happens.

Any suggestion, direction and examples welcome.

P.S.: This will be production so we want to chose less problematic way :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think MQTT is overhyped , sure the result I think is due to available open source servers. Zeromq does offer a lot of features to build something that will meet the requirements. The more I look at the options available , the more i am leaning towards zeromq. In our case, we will be receiving data at random intervals from a very large number of devices ( gateway's in a mesh network or End nodes themsevles ). Our finalized message size is very simple , a delimited string , binary encoded , zipped ( <100 Bytes) and sent over the wire. I am decided on zeromq on the server to receive messages. Reasons are not merely based on zeromq as a broker but also how We can utilize its curveZmq features to make provisioning of devices easy and allowing for a simple ZTP (Zero Touch Provisioning system) and key manageability . I am at the preset time debating on using pub/sub vs push /pull patterns where in each end device is a publisher or pusher with a proxy subscriber on the cloud server. while typically pub in a pub/sub there are fewer publishers and more subscribers in a typical large scale IOT deployment there are more publishers and fewer subscribers so it makes me wonder if i should go with pub/sub and there there is the problem of loosing messages due to slow joining subscriber - what if we bring down the server for maintenance , devices in the field would keep publishing messages until HWM is reached. Guess there is always a risk of loosing messages irrespective of anything ex - backhaul network is down and the device Hits the HWM - this is out of control.

Malamute does not have much documentation else i would have explored it a bit more.

So , have you decided on what to use ? If you want to persist messages until they are consumed , i strongly suggest zeromq as a proxy with workers pushing messages into a persistent store .. you can get creative here as well with including a sequence # etc..and allowing clients to request messages given a sequence range etc if they are lost .

Comment: thanks for your time and elagent informative reply. I will surely take a look and test zmq. what is worried me that development looks like little bit old.

Comment: This answer is still true . Despite the buzz as said. Brokerless, well documented, wide range of  supported langages ZeroMQ  still does the job

Answer (score 4):

> **`A:`** *We need to deliver this message 100% and do not want to lose any message.*
>   **`B:`** *Messages should queued in the server until consumers connected if anything happens.*
>   **`C:`** *This will be production so we want to choose a less problematic way :)*

`A:` is doable
`A: + B:` is doable, harder, yet still doable
`A: + B: + C:` is not, this composition of requirements does come at cost

> **`D:`** *Any suggestion, direction and examples welcome.*

ZeroMQ comes at hand, as being **lightweight**, out of question, tunable / tweakable **way beyond** the cited throughput of **`~ 45 [kb / 5 min]`**, yet the Devil comes at proper understanding of the strengths of the **Zen-of-Zero**, the package, as-is, **by design strives to provide ZERO WARRANTY** and lets all kind users design their own, use-case-specific ( read as a "just-enough"-warranty one needs, so not losing a single bit of efficiency for the rest of the world use-cases ).

So, the **`D:`** goes into spending a proper amount of design-efforts for covering the "*costs*"-of-**`C:`** and you have met the design target.

So easy, this is a common task for any and all CTO-s to face this and decide next steps.

### Bonus part

If in a need to minimise the IoT-devices' requirements, may go and compare these **`costs`**-of-`C:` with a similar custom-adaptation of even a more lightweight framework for Scalable Formal Communication Pattern Archetypes, that was designed by Martin Sustrik *et al*, as a younger sister of the ZeroMQ one -- the **[nanomsg](/questions/tagged/nanomsg)**, there might be some saving on low-power / scarcer resources, as commonly present in massive cohorts of IoT-devices.

Comment: Any comparison between MQTT and ZeroMQ regarding to this A,B,C concept ?

Answer (score 2):

In the real world there is no such thing as 'guaranteed delivery', as things can go wrong on many levels: hardware, network, network interface, routing, memory limits, and many more. (For example, RabbitMQ stores data in memory, but what happens on sudden reboot, or when running out of memory?)
What people usually mean when they say 'guaranteed delivery' is that there is some detection and retry mechanism. This is usally a matter of designing your application, and not the used product. In a distributed network, it is impossible to have 100% knowledge of the entire state.

First of all, ZeroMQ is a library, and not a product. This means that (with a few lines of code) you can make any type of architecture with any type of redundancy. ZeroMQ is brokerless, meaning there is no single point of failure - but if you really want, you could write a brokersystem using ZMQ.

MQTT is a PUB/SUB system that uses a broker that checks the delivery of messages. This introduces a single-point-of-failure.

ZeroMQ has many more sockettypes then just PUB/SUB, for different usecases, where MQTT only knows PUB/SUB.

Zyre is a messagingsystem build for instable networks that guarantees delivery (within limits). It is build using the ZeroMQ buildingblocks, and probably best for IoT

Comment: "In a distributed network, it is impossible to have 100% knowledge of the entire state."
This is at least misleading. The Chandy Lamport algorithm is exactly addressing this topic. Creating a snapshot of a state in a distributed system.